# IntelliJ IDEA switch-case not properly indenting on break

Tags: intellij-idea

I have to manually (shift) backspace just to fix the indentation. How to fix this?

```
switch(choice) {
      case 0:
        printInstructions();
        break;
        case 1: <--- this should be inline with case 0: when I hit enter after the break;
        groceryList.printGroceryList();
        break;    
    }
```

Comment: I did explore the switch indentation from Wrapping and Braces but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue:

- [IDEA-178127](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178127) Pressing Enter after 'break' in 'switch' should put the caret at 'case' indentation level

However, once you type `case 1:`, it will be indented automatically (as soon as you type `:`).